# A crime/detective story where the protagonist tells his murder story in great detail and still roams free

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I read this story almost ten years ago and forgot its name. Google search isn't helping me to find it.

**The story goes like this:**

The murderer kills his ex, not out of spite, but for love; not love for his ex, but for his poultry farm that he so much adored and cared for.

A detective then follows him, determined to bring him into justice, but it did not faze him. Instead of getting nervous, he stays calm and starts to write a detective story, a story that explains the murder in great detail and what he did with the dead body, and yet, the detective has nothing to do, he knows, but he can't do anything.

It was probably written by a writer who wrote only this one detective story in his lifetime and was awarded for it after his death (his family got the award money) [This information may be incorrect, I don't remember much].

Can anyone tell me the name of the story?

**[Major Spoiler Alert]**

**Motivation to kill**

She came back probably a year after she left him for someone else, who was a bit more masculine, aggressive and possessive. He knew, even though that type of character attracted her at first but in the end, she will get bored and come back. Well, it did happen, she fled and came to him in secret without telling anyone. Then she was telling her stories, how she fled, how she etc. etc. blah, blah. He pretty much guessed that she now wants to live with him again. But things have changed for him, he is now more interested in raising poultry than loving a woman. He started thinking, "If we get together, I will have to give her time which I don't have. A bit of time off my schedule will hamper my raising my poultry, not to mention, it's a delicate season for them. A little bit of unawareness can cause an epidemic and all my hard work for the whole season will be gone, just like that. I can't have that, sorry."
After thinking like that he was searching for a solution in his head. Thinking very hard, he finally decided that murder is the only solution.

**What he did to the body**

What he did to the dead body was really gruesome but ingenious.

He made a kind of poultry feed out of it (using some sort of machine), the bones were turned into something like powdery substance. Then he fed it to them, they gave him lots of eggs. He sold his poultry with a condition to give him back the bones after eating. He then processed these bones to make fertilizer for his lands.

The eggs, some he sold and some he hatched and sent some second generation of poultry to the detective along with a copy of his published story book.

Comment: Please include all the information that you can remember, yeah, including spoilers ;)

Comment: @Mithrandir : done, added more details.

Comment: @user14111 : yes

Comment: "*[A former murder squad detective in the Metropolitan Police who now helps run one of Northern Ireland's largest chicken farms has revealed the career change was all for the love of a good man.](https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/the-murder-cop-who-gave-it-all-up-for-love-and-life-on-the-farm-34210987.html)*" - sounds like a real-life inverted version of this story!

Comment: The coverup reminds me of Dahl's Lamb to the Slaughter, and the general confession reminds me of this Key and Peele Skit I loved (some harsh language): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14WE3A0PwVs ... it's really cool to see so many different spins on the concept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The story appears to be *Being a Murderer Myself* by Arthur Williams and is most famous for being [adapted by James P Cavanagh as 'Arthur' for the fifth season of Alfred Hitchcock Presents](http://www.themoviewaffler.com/2014/11/hitchcock-in-reverse-arthur-1959.html).
The story was originally published in Ellery Queen's Mystery Magazine in August 1948
I can't find an online copy of the story, but a synopsis from [The Hitchcock Zone](https://the.hitchcock.zone/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock_Presents_-_Arthur) says of the episode:

> Arthur Williams is a chicken farmer who is also a confirmed bachelor. He wants to be rid of his gold-digging girlfriend. He strangles and kills her. The police suspect Arthur, but cannot find the body. Later Arthur offers them a gift for their troubles: chickens. The chickens are quite fat from a special feed that was made up, in part, from his girlfriend's body.

Comment: Found an [audio](http://mp3pn.info/song/46425436/BBC_-_Horror_-_Being_a_Murderer_Myself_by_Arthur_Williams/)